# I can see notifications about my own suggested edits waiting review, but I don't see them in review queue

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, notifications

I'm editing some tags on Anime&Manga and whenever I do that, the review notification appears with the number of my edits currently waiting to be reviewed. Why show them to me if I can't do anything about them?